# MS Outlook 2010 headers mixing

Tags: css, html, header, outlook

I'm definitely not a CSS nor HTML expert, but I think my code is correct. When I run it in Internet Explorer it works fine and shows some white space between the headers, as it should be. But when I sent it to MS Outlook 2010 the headers are mixing. And I can't seem to find a way to fix this in a clean way...

**MS Outlook 2010 (Not OK):**

[image: MS Outlook 2010]

**Internet Explorer (OK):**

[image]

**HTML/CSS-Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><style type="text/css">
body {
    font-family:verdana;
    background-color:white;
}
h1 {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    text-indent:10px;
}
h2 {
    background-color:lightGrey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-indent:10px;
}
p {
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
</style></head><body>
<h1>My Big Title</h1>
<h2>My Smaller title:</h2>
<p>Hello world :)</p>
</body></html>
```

Thank you for your help on solving this little nasty issue.

Changing `h1` to `margin-bottom:10px;` doesn't fix it either:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by adding `page-break-before: always;` as found in [this post](http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/horizontal_spacing_issues_in_outlook_2007_and_2010).

Man I'm glad I solved this one! Has been bugging me a long time now.

**Fix:**

```
h1 {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-indent:10px;
    page-break-before: always;
}
h2 {
    background-color:lightGrey;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-indent:10px;
    page-break-before: always;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Internet explorer probably applies default browser margins to the header elements which explains why the top and bottom text are pushed under each other.
If your first line of text is the Big Title, try updating

`h1 {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    text-indent:10px;
}`

with

`h1 {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    text-indent:10px;
}`

This will apply a 10 pixel margin at the bottom of your first h1 text. You can change value to your needs.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't fix it in Outlook 2010. I've updated the OP with a screenshot.